# Python: Replacing values with underlying distribution

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data-frame, in which one column has 3 values i.e. 0.0,1.0 & 35.0. Basically, 35.0 are nulls but somehow nulls are being interpreted as 35.0. Value counts looks like below:

```
home_ownership
0.0      1090
1.0     38531
35.0      379
Name: Id, dtype: int64
```

I need to replace all my `35.0` with 0s or 1s based on the underlying existing distribution of 0s and 1s.

Would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Given your data distribution you can use simple random number generation

```
>> n_zeros, n_ones = 1090, 38531
>> n_samples = n_zeros + n_ones
>> n_nulls = 379
>> df.loc[np.isclose(df['home_ownership'], 35.0), 'home_ownership'] = \
         [float(random.randint(0, n_samples) >= n_zeros) for _ in range(n_nulls)]
```

Explanation: `float(random.randint(0, n_samples) >= n_zeros)` generates random number from distribution `{0.0: n_zeros/n_samples, 1.0: n_ones/n_samples}`.

Note: You can replace

```
[float(random.randint(0, n_samples) >= n_zeros) for _ in range(n_nulls)]
```

with

```
np.random.choice([0.0, 1.0], n_nulls, p=[n_zeros/n_samples, n_ones/n_samples])
```

or with

```
np.random.binomial(1, n_ones/n_samples, n_nulls).astype(float)
```

Comment: @user4943236 Added some clarification

Answer (score 1):

Without hard-coding the sizes of each group or importing anything new, you can do it by exploiting the sample method:

```
n = home_ownership.shape[0]
valid_subset = home_ownership[home_ownership.col!=35.0]
distribution = valid_subset.col.sample(n, replace=True).values
home_ownership.col.where(home_ownership.col!=35.0, other=distribution, inplace=True)
```

- n is the shape of your array
- distribution is an array of the same size picked from the 0's and 1's (with replacement).
- Keep all values that are not 35, otherwise use the corresponding value in the representative distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following approach:

```
sm = 1090+38531

df.loc[np.isclose(df.a, 35.), 'a'] = np.random.choice([0.,1.], 379, p=[1090/sm, 38531/sm])
```